# Implicit ExecutionContext in traits

Tags: scala, concurrency

I would like to have an implicit ExecutionContext passed to a partially implemented trait.
In code example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Processor[T,R] {
  def process(op:T): Future[R] = {
    //Do something to get stuff from abstract methods
    Future {
      //Do something that returns type R
    }
  }
}
```

This will ask for an ExecutionContext, so I have changed the declaration to:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait Processor[T,R] {
  def process(op:T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[R] = {
    //Do something to get stuff from abstract methods
    Future {
      //Do something that returns type R
    }
  }
}
```

But then when I try to extend the trait like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class StringProcessor extends Processor[String,String] {
  //Bla bla bla
}
```

The compiler tells me that the method process is not implemented an my class should be abstract.

How can I ensure that my construct works without having to put an `implicit val xc:ExecutionContext` in the declaration of the trait?

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to be having any issues with the following code, which is similar to your code but provides a full implementation.  Not sure what the issue is.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait Processor[T,R] {
  def process(op:T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[R] = {
    //Do something to get stuff from abstract methods
    Future {
      getR
    }
  }

  def getR:R
}

class StringProcessor extends Processor[String,String] {
  def getR = "foo"
}
```